Interact with SOAP API - cannot find object definition in wsdl?
I am currencty trying to make a soap client capable of creating a folder using the SOAP API.
It should be pretty simple according to this - there is even a codesnippet
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/creating_retrieving_updating_and_deleting_folders.html
private void CreateDataFolder()
{
    SoapClient framework2 = new SoapClient();
    framework2.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "xxx";
    framework2.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "xxx";
    String requestID;
    String status;
    DataFolder datafolder = new DataFolder();
    datafolder.Name = "API Created Folder";
    datafolder.Description = "API Created Folder";
    datafolder.ParentFolder = new DataFolder();
    datafolder.ParentFolder.ID = 12345; // This is the ID of the 'my emails' folder that you can get from doing a retrieve
    datafolder.ParentFolder.IDSpecified = true;
    datafolder.ContentType = "email";
    CreateResult[] cresults = framework2.Create(new CreateOptions(), new APIObject[] { datafolder }, out requestID, out status);
    foreach (CreateResult result in cresults)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result.StatusMessage);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(requestID + ": " + status);
}

I tried using both the enterprise wsdl and partner wsdl and cannot seem to find a definition of Datafolder or CreateResult -  where are these object defines, as it clearly looks like something the soap api response as an object?
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/createresult.html
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/datafolder.html
So where are they defined?
